# Spacing between blocks in Swift 100% width

Tags: swift, ios8, width, block

Im testing some stuff for an app in SWIFT. My goal is to have the full screen covered in blocks, so it give a 100% width and height. but for some reason, theres always 1px or 2px spacing.

I think its because when i screenWidth is 320px, and I try to split it with 3 blocks, that would give 106,6666px pr block which is not possible.

[image: IOS8 preview]

Anyone got a good idea how to solve this? Should i maybe just add 1px if the number is uneven?

Comment: Are you using UICollectionView?

Comment: No im not, im very new to swift and iOS development, so havnt looked at that yet.. but thats maybe the way to go?